# NHibernate Profiler is lying to me?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, decimal, nhprof

### Im using Fluent NHibernate as my ORM and NH Profiler is throwing me this sql query when I execute it

```
INSERT INTO [Location]
        (Name,
         Lat,
         Lon)
VALUES      ('my address' /* @p0 */,
         -58.37538459999996 /* @p1 */,
         -34.5969468 /* @p2 */);
```

---

which is absolutly correct by the way. 
This is the design of my Location table:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Lat] [decimal](23, 20) NULL,
[Lon] [decimal](23, 20) NULL,
```

---

But when I see the inserted data in sqlserver management studio, I can see it inserted

-58.37538000000000000000 instead of -58.37538459999996000000 and

-34.59694000000000000000 instead of -34.59694680000000000000.

When I execute this insert query manually, it inserts the values correctly (the 14 decimals for Lat Column) , but if nhibernate does this, it only inserts 5 decimals.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes with the default `precision` and `scale`. NHibernate default `decimal` representation is `decimal (28,5)`, so that's why the final INSERT statement contains only 5 decimal places. XML mapping

```
<property name="Lat" precision="23" scale="20" />
<property name="Lon" precision="23" scale="20" />
```

fluent:

```
...
.Precision(23)
.Scale(20)
```

Now the INSERT statement will be `decimal (23,20)`.

Comment: Thank you!. That is exactly what i've been looking for.